# How do I generalize the product for the totient function to a slightly related function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

I already know that
    $\phi(n) = n\prod_{p\text{ divides }n}(1-\frac{1}{p})$.
Suppose I define a closely related function $\phi(n,x;i,q)$ s.t.
$\phi(n,x;i,q) = \sum_{1\leq j\leq x, \gcd(j,n)=1,j\equiv i\pmod q}1$
what is a related product for this function? **I just need bounds for the product.**

Comment: Your sum has a problem did you mean $j\equiv i \bmod q$ ? First of all there is no product over the primes for $\sum_{j \le x, \gcd(j,n)=1} 1$, with the inclusion exclusion it is $=\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) \lfloor x/d\rfloor$ and the floor simplifies only when $x$ is a multiple of $n$

Comment: If it is impossible to find a product, find lower and upper bounds for this function.

Comment: $$x\phi(n)/n -\tau(n) \le \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) \lfloor x/d\rfloor \le x\phi(n)/n + \tau(n)$$